# How comma operator is used between the statements?

Tags: javascript, comma-operator

The description of comma operator says

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression

And the syntax and parameters also says that its operands should be expressions.

#### Syntax

> expr1, expr2, expr3...

#### Parameters

> `expr1`, `expr2`, `expr3`...
> Any expressions.

I want to know that why the following code doesnot throw error while it have a declaration `let x = 3`

```js
let x = 3,
    y = 5
console.log(x,y)
```

If you put declaration in `console.log()` it throws error it means its not expression.

```js
console.log(let x = 3,y=3)
```

Comment: Because ```x = 3``` is a expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only parsed as the comma operator when between *expressions*, not statements. `let x = 3` is not an expression; it does not evaluate to any value. Trying to parse it as an expression does not work:

```js
const result = let x = 3;
console.log(result);
```

The syntax `let <variableName> = <expression>, <variableName2> = <expression2>` is not invoking the comma operator - that syntax, when used around `let`, `const`, and `var`, simply initializes multiple variables at once, and said syntax simply *happens* to use commas, despite the fact that they're not interpreted as the comma operator.

In contrast, with

```js
let x = 3,
    y = 5
console.log(x,y)
```

You're not invoking the comma operator here, either: you have a *parameter list*. To invoke the comma operator, you also need to be not immediately inside a parameter list, eg:

```js
let x = 3,
    y = 5
console.log((x,y))
```

or

```js
let x = 3,
    y = 5
const someVar = (x,y);
console.log(someVar);
```